# use xsl-apply templates for one-to-many mappings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to do a one-to-many mapping using XSL and I seem to be stuck.

I have a parent tag structure called Channel, that is made of 1-to-many Framework tags. Each framework tag can in turn be made of 1-to-many backend tags. Here is my source XML.

```
    <ESBConfig>
    <Channels>
        <Channel ChannelId="SMS">
            <Name>SMS Banking</Name>
            <dependentFrameworks>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW001">This is to call FW001</FW>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW002">This is to call FW002</FW>
            </dependentFrameworks>
        </Channel>
        <Channel ChannelId="IBK">
            <Name>Internet Banking</Name>
            <dependentFrameworks>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW001">This is to call FW001</FW>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW002">This is to call FW002</FW>
            </dependentFrameworks>
        </Channel>
    </Channels>
    <Frameworks>
        <Framework FrameworkId="FW001">
            <Name>Framework 001</Name>
            <dependentBackends>
                <BE BackendRef="BED001">This is to call BED001</BE>
                <BE BackendRef="BED002">This is to call BED002</BE>
            </dependentBackends>
        </Framework>
        <Framework FrameworkId="FW002">
            <Name>Framework 002</Name>
            <dependentBackends>
                <BE BackendRef="BED001">This is to call BED001</BE>
                <BE BackendRef="BED002">This is to call BED002</BE>
            </dependentBackends>
        </Framework>
    </Frameworks>
    <Backends>
        <Backend BackendId="BED001">
            <Name>Backend 1</Name>
        </Backend>
        <Backend BackendId="BED002">
            <Name>Backend 2</Name>
        </Backend>
    </Backends>
</ESBConfig>
```

In my XSL,I am using apply-templates and xsl call-templates. But I am stuck traversing the tree for 1-to-many relationships. This is the target XML i wish to construct.

```
<ESBConfig>
    <Channel ChannelId="SMS">
        <Name>SMS Banking</Name>
        <dependentFrameworks>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW001">
                <Name>Framework 1</Name>
                <dependentBackends>
                    <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                        <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                    </Backend>
                    <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                        <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                    </Backend>
                </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW002">
                <Name>Framework 2</Name>
                <dependentBackends>
                    <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                        <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                    </Backend>
                    <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                        <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                    </Backend>
                </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
        </dependentFrameworks>
    </Channel>
</ESBConfig>
```

This is the code I have used so far, but I am unable to iterate over the number of backends for a given framework id. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ESBConfig">
        <xsl:variable name="channelName">
            <xsl:value-of select="'SMS'"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="frameworkRef">
            <xsl:value-of select="/ESBConfig/Channels/Channel[@ChannelId=$channelName]/dependentFrameworks/FW/@FrameworkRef"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="backendRef">
            <xsl:value-of select="/ESBConfig/Frameworks/Framework[@FrameworkId=$frameworkRef]/dependentBackends/BE/@BackendRef"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr>
            <Level2>
                <xsl:element name="channelName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$channelName"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <channelName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'SMS'"/>
                </channelName>
            </Level2>
            <Level1>
                <xsl:element name="frameworkRef">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$frameworkRef"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <framework>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/ESBConfig/Frameworks/Framework[@FrameworkId=$frameworkRef]"/>
                </framework>
            </Level1>
            <Level0>
                <xsl:variable name="snippet">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/ESBConfig/Frameworks/Framework[@FrameworkId=$frameworkRef]/dependentBackends/BE"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="$snippet/BE">
                    <xsl:variable name="temp">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@BackendRef"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <Bref>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$temp"/>
                    </Bref>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Level0>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ESBConfig/Backends">
        <xsl:param name="bid"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Backend[@BackendId=$bid]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of the approach Martin Honnen is talking about. It's a lot different than your sample XSLT (which is creating `tr`'s and `Level#` elements), but matches the desired output*.

*The output does contain all `Channel` elements and the `Channels` wrapper element where the requested output only has the `SMS` channel. If you need to limit the output to a single channel, I would recommend adding an `xsl:param` and a predicate to the `Channel` in the select. Let me know if you would like an updated example.

**XML Input**

```
<ESBConfig>
    <Channels>
        <Channel ChannelId="SMS">
            <Name>SMS Banking</Name>
            <dependentFrameworks>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW001">This is to call FW001</FW>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW002">This is to call FW002</FW>
            </dependentFrameworks>
        </Channel>
        <Channel ChannelId="IBK">
            <Name>Internet Banking</Name>
            <dependentFrameworks>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW001">This is to call FW001</FW>
                <FW FrameworkRef="FW002">This is to call FW002</FW>
            </dependentFrameworks>
        </Channel>
    </Channels>
    <Frameworks>
        <Framework FrameworkId="FW001">
            <Name>Framework 001</Name>
            <dependentBackends>
                <BE BackendRef="BED001">This is to call BED001</BE>
                <BE BackendRef="BED002">This is to call BED002</BE>
            </dependentBackends>
        </Framework>
        <Framework FrameworkId="FW002">
            <Name>Framework 002</Name>
            <dependentBackends>
                <BE BackendRef="BED001">This is to call BED001</BE>
                <BE BackendRef="BED002">This is to call BED002</BE>
            </dependentBackends>
        </Framework>
    </Frameworks>
    <Backends>
        <Backend BackendId="BED001">
            <Name>Backend 1</Name>
        </Backend>
        <Backend BackendId="BED002">
            <Name>Backend 2</Name>
        </Backend>
    </Backends>
</ESBConfig>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="frameworks" match="Framework" use="@FrameworkId"/>
    <xsl:key name="backends" match="Backend" use="@BackendId"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Channels"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FW">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('frameworks',@FrameworkRef)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BE">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('backends',@BackendRef)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<ESBConfig>
   <Channels>
      <Channel ChannelId="SMS">
         <Name>SMS Banking</Name>
         <dependentFrameworks>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW001">
               <Name>Framework 001</Name>
               <dependentBackends>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                     <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                  </Backend>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                     <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                  </Backend>
               </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW002">
               <Name>Framework 002</Name>
               <dependentBackends>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                     <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                  </Backend>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                     <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                  </Backend>
               </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
         </dependentFrameworks>
      </Channel>
      <Channel ChannelId="IBK">
         <Name>Internet Banking</Name>
         <dependentFrameworks>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW001">
               <Name>Framework 001</Name>
               <dependentBackends>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                     <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                  </Backend>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                     <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                  </Backend>
               </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
            <Framework FrameworkId="FW002">
               <Name>Framework 002</Name>
               <dependentBackends>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED001">
                     <Name>Backend 1</Name>
                  </Backend>
                  <Backend BackendId="BED002">
                     <Name>Backend 2</Name>
                  </Backend>
               </dependentBackends>
            </Framework>
         </dependentFrameworks>
      </Channel>
   </Channels>
</ESBConfig>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two keys, the first one is `<xsl:key name="fw" match="Framework" use="@FrameworkId"/>`, then use it inside of a template matching your `Channel` to process `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('fw', dependentFramework/Framework/@FrameworkRef)"/>`. You can use the same approach to follow the other cross-reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  tag. Example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Channel">
    <!-- Your code here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

The for-each works just like in any other programming language:
It selects every occurence of the Tag in the select attribute and does what follows for each of them.

Comment: Once I identify FW001 for the channel (SMS), I have to go to the Framework structure and retrieve occurrences of BED001 and BED002. Basically a parent child relationship where all structures are linked together by their ID. So the linkage is SMS --> FW001 --> BED001 and BED002.